# Does self-demodulation occur in air when ultrasonic waves are modulated and transmitted with audible sound?

Tags: acoustics

I have heard that there is a technology that modulates ultrasonic waves into audible sound through multiple paths and sends them out. The reason for using this technology to send the voice as much as possible in a specific direction is because ultrasonic waves have sharp directivity and straight-line properties. However, as the frequency increases, the attenuation in the air is severe, and I do not understand how it can be transmitted farther. Also, it is said that it is self-demodulating without a demodulation signal, but how do you know the demodulation distance? I would like to ask those who have data or experience related to it.

Comment: Do you have a reference to put this question in better context?  The human ear is nonlinear and could potentially demodulate some information on a high-level ultrasonic carrier

Comment: Of course, but it is not said to be formal. Sorry not to accept your demand..